# Como abrir arquivos com acento no nome - FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

O caminho para os arquivos estão em um array de String. Alguns arquivos tem nome com acento e estão gerando `FileNotFoundException`

```
   /**
    * Realiza leitura dos dados de um arquivo.
    * @param s - string com endereco do diretorio do arquivo    
    */
   public void ler(String s) {

      String dados = "";
      String linha;

      try {

         FileReader f = new FileReader(s);
         BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);

         while(b.ready()){

            linha = b.readLine();
            dados += linha;
         }

         this.dados = dados;

         b.close();
         f.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {

         MyIO.println("METODO LER() ====> " + e.toString());

      } finally{
      }  
   }
```

Exemplo dos nomes dos arquivos:

```
/tmp/personagens/Cordé.txt
/tmp/personagens/Dormé.txt
/tmp/personagens/JabbaDesilijicTiure.txt
/tmp/personagens/JangoFett.txt
/tmp/personagens/JarJarBinks.txt
/tmp/personagens/PadméAmidala.txt
/tmp/personagens/RicOlié.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário converter a String com o nome do Arquivo para UTF-8:

```
byte[] isoBytes = strISO.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String ISOtoUTF = new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8");
```

Uso no código:

```
   public void ler(String s) {

      String dados = "";
      String linha;

      try {

         byte [] isoBytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
         FileReader f = new FileReader(new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"));
         BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);

         while(b.ready()){

            linha = b.readLine();
            dados += linha;
         }

         this.dados = dados;

         b.close();
         f.close();

      } catch (IOException e1) {    
         MyIO.println(e1.toString());    
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {    
         MyIO.println(e2.toString());    
      } finally{
      }  
   }
```